# Cannot write a file from code in the App_Code folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

The legacy ASP.Net system I am working in uses "**aquarium framework**" and when you press a button it executes code within a handler.

This handler sits within **App_Code\Rules**.

When I attempt to write a text file from this code, the file is not produced and there is no error either.

The code I'm using to write the file is used in other places without incident but when I call this code from App_Code\Rules, the file is not produced.

The code that writes the file looks like this;

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear()
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" & FileName.Replace(New Char() {" "c}, New Char() {"."c}) & ".csv")
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(ExportString)
```

Any thoughts as to what might be happening and why the file is not being produced?

**EDIT**

After the call to Write, I look at the Status and it is "200 OK".

Comment: Hi, have you checked event viewer for any warning or error?

Comment: I have and there is nothing in there that indicates it failed to write the file.  Not in the Application or the security logs.  I even cleared them out and ran the code and there was nothing.